# Issue with calling repositories from Spring MVC controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo, spring-data

I have a Spring MVC application **with repositories (`@Repository`) injected directly into some controllers (`@Controller`)** thus sometimes bypassing the Service layer.

For example: I have several `findByXXX` methods in my repositories and I did not find a way to automatically generate wrapper methods around custom methods in my services using Spring Roo.

I therefore have a dilemma: **either bypass the Service layer (bad) or spend a lot of time (bad) creating simple wrapper methods in the Service layer around my custom repository methods.**

*Has anyone got a solution to this dilemma?*

**Edit 1**: Here is one of my controllers as requested by @Nabil:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/signup")
public class SignupController {

    @Autowired
    private SignupService signupService;

    @Autowired
    private SigninService signinService;

    @Autowired
    private MemberRepository memberRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PreferenceService preferenceService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
    public String signupForm(@ModelAttribute SignupInfo signupInfo, Model model) {
        populateForm(model, signupInfo);
        return "signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
    public String signup(@ModelAttribute @Validated({ Validation.Signup.class }) SignupInfo signupInfo, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        if (!preferenceService.isEmailAvailable(signupInfo.getMember().getEmail())) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("member.email", "controller.signup.email_already_used");
        }

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            populateForm(model, signupInfo);
            return "signup";
        }

        signupService.signupMember(signupInfo.getMember(), signupInfo.getAddressReference());
        signinService.signin(memberRepository.findByEmail(signupInfo.getMember().getEmail()));
        return "redirect:preference/email";
    }

    private void populateForm(Model model, SignupInfo signupInfo) {
        model.addAttribute("signupInfo", signupInfo);
        model.addAttribute("roles", Arrays.asList(Role.ROLE_BASIC_CHILDMINDER, Role.ROLE_BASIC_FAMILY));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you send an example of one of your controller methods

Answer (score 4):

The solution would be to put your **whole business logic into services**. The responsibility of the controller should be solely to translate the HTTP request into a **single service call** and than translate the result, or exception, into HTTP response. The service should call all repositories and other services required to perform the business operation.

As for several `findByXXX`, the delegation is not a bad thing. However I'd go with a universal single method `findAll(Predicate p)` in the repository layer. I.e. like [Spring Data JPA docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#specifications) suggest, or even better using [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/). Then the service layer would construct the predicate instead of just delegating to lower layer.